# RMarkdown page break after kable tables and then show plots

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown, knitr, kable

I have an RMarkdown file that contains the code chunk below. I want the histogram plot to show up on the page after the two `kable` tables. i.e., I want the histogram plot to print on page 3. But in my output, it always prints on page 2. Even if I have multiple `\pagebreak` values after one another, the plot still prints on page 2.

I've researched a while this morning, and have not been able to come across a solution. The code below uses `mtcars`, so it should be completely reproducible.

````
```
---
title: "Test Document"
author: ""
date: "Today's Date"
output: pdf_document
classoption: landscape
---
  
```{r knitr_init, echo = FALSE, results="asis", cache = FALSE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE}
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(kableExtra)

data(mtcars)
```

```{r, echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE}
cars_table <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarise(avg_hp = mean(hp))

kable(cars_table,
      align = 'r',
      caption = "Average Horsepower by Cylinders",
      format="latex")
```

```{r, echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE}
cars_table <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(gear) %>%
  summarise(avg_hp = mean(hp))

kable(cars_table,
      align = 'r',
      caption = "Average Horsepower by Gears",
      format="latex")
```
\pagebreak
```{r, echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE, fig1, fig.height = 4, fig.width = 10}
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  facet_wrap(~cyl)
```
````

Comment: Does using "\newpage" instead of "\pagebreak" work? Just saw it looking at this rmarkdown site and thought maybe it would help: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/pagebreaks.html

Comment: @Silentdevildoll unfortunately, it produces the same result. Replacing `\pagebreak` with `\newpage` still does not achieve the result of printing the ggplot on page 3.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of hackerish, but a blank "header" markdown line followed by `\pagebreak` in two separate locations did the trick.

````
---
title: "Test Document"
author: ""
date: "Today's Date"
output: pdf_document
classoption: landscape
---
  
```{r knitr_init, echo = FALSE, results="asis", cache = FALSE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE}
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(kableExtra)

data(mtcars)
```
#
\pagebreak
```{r, echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE}
cars_table <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarise(avg_hp = mean(hp))

kable(cars_table,
      align = 'r',
      caption = "Average Horsepower by Cylinders",
      format="latex")
```

```{r, echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE}
cars_table <- mtcars %>%
  group_by(gear) %>%
  summarise(avg_hp = mean(hp))

kable(cars_table,
      align = 'r',
      caption = "Average Horsepower by Gears",
      format="latex")
```
#
\pagebreak
```{r, echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE, fig1, fig.height = 4, fig.width = 10}
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  facet_wrap(~cyl)
```
````